# Случайное отправка сообщения из массива для бота на dicrord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

я новичок и делаю бота на питоне для дискорда. Я решил использовать массивы, для того, чтобы бот мог случайно отправлять сообщения из этого массива. Мне не хватает знаний для реализации и буду благодарен за помощь

Comment: что именно не получается?

Comment: Я не знаю как сделать, чтобы из массива выбиралось случайное значение

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html

Comment: и что мне с этим необходимо сделать

Answer (score 5, accepted):

случайное значение из массив можно получить с помощью `random.choice` пример:

```
import random


arr = [0, 2, 3, 5]

print(random.choice(arr))
```